# PDF logo location

Tags: pdf

Good afternoon,

Where is the Magento logo coming from for PDFs created by the Magento website?

I tried to replace root favicon.ico with my custom favicon, all skin/favicon.ico files, media/favicon.ico files,
cleared browser cache,
but PDFs are still showing the default Magento logo.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can set favicon through adminpanel `system > configuration > general > design > Html head > favicon`

Answer (score 2):

PDF logo image can be set at `System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slips Design`